# Drag and Drop javascript dynamics elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to do this:

> When user drag a **new Card** to the **Board**, javascript clone default Card. Now, I want to able drag this Card and **move (not clone)** it to other section of Board.

Now I have this:
**drag**

```
boardApp.directive('draggable',function(){
return function(scope,elem){
    var el = elem[0];
    el.draggable=true;
    el.addEventListener('dragstart',function(event){
        console.log(this.classList);
        if(this.classList.contains("drag")){
            event.dataTransfer.setData('movePostIt',this.id);
        }else{
            event.dataTransfer.setData('postIt',this.id);
        }
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
        this.classList.add('drag');
        return false;
    },false);
    el.addEventListener('dragend',function(event){
        this.classList.remove('drag');
        return false;
    },false);
};
});
```

and **drop**

```
boardApp.directive('droppable',function(){
return function(scope,elem){
    var el = elem[0];
    el.addEventListener('dragover',function(event){
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        this.classList.add('over');
        return false;
    },false);
    el.addEventListener('dragenter',function(event){
        this.classList.add('over');
        return false;
    },false);
    el.addEventListener('dragleave',function(event){
        this.classList.remove('over');
        return false;
    },false);
    el.addEventListener('drop',function(event){
        if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
        this.classList.remove('over');
        var id = event.dataTransfer.getData("postIt");
        console.log(id);
        var item = document.getElementById(id).cloneNode(true);
        item.classList.remove('drag');
        console.log(item.className);
        item.removeAttribute("style");

        this.appendChild(item.cloneNode(true));
        return false;
    },false);

};
});
```

However, when I clone this Card i also copy draggable attribute but this Card is **NOT** draggable.

You have any idea about what's happening? Any solution?
Thank you.

***EDIT***
Here is the link to my app.
**https://hidden-everglades-8767.herokuapp.com/board/#/545bb3e9b36a067516000001**

Comment: Can we have a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry I can't post a fiddle because code is complicated but I have added to my answer a link to one board on my app.

If you are interested to see my complete code I will be happy to show you.
Thank you.